# Integration of Spring application with Mule ESB

Tags: java, spring, mule, pojo

We have deployed our **spring 3 application** in tomcat server. We would like to expose few of our pojo services as web service using **mule ESB** . We are using **mule 3.1** community edition.

One way identified for this is, deploy the same **pojo services**  as jar  in mule server . But in this case same code will be  running in  two containers. Is there any other way to access spring **pojo services** in mule  server for exposing as  **web services**.

Answer (score 0):

You could use spring remoting [1] to expose the existing pojo services, running in tomcat, over RMI or HTTP Invoker.
Then in the in mule you can write a component that calls this external pojo service, again you can use spring remoting to create this client component.

Another option is to expose the pojo services as webservices, running in tomcat. For this you can use either spring remoting or spring-ws. Then you can use use mule as a webservice proxy, possibly with transformation to expose a better public API.

[1] http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html

[2] http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/

// Pontus

Comment: If we choose first option ,can we expose the original service running in tomcat server as web service

Comment: Yes, this was my suggestion.